# Можно ли сделать график в Excel, если значения перечислены через запятую в одном и том же столбце?

Tags: excel

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать график в Excel, если оба значения (и x, и y) перечислены через запятую в одном и том же столбце?

Значений слишком много, чтобы можно было в ручную их разделить.

Очень нужно.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: @Snaut, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Excel такую запись воспринимает как текст. Данные нужно разделять.

Возможное решение - Разнести данные по столбцам.

Меню **Данные-Текст_по_столбцам, Разделитель - запятая**, дальше по шагам, указать начальную ячейку для сохранения полученного диапазона.

Потом собрать отдельно Х, отдельно Y.

Второе возможное решение - макросом.

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо!